# How to remove MariaDB and install MySQL for Postfix?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, postfix-mta, mail-server

I have removed MariaDB completely and installed MySQL V.8 but now when I want to install postfix with `yum install postfix`. Its dependencies are `MariaDB-common` and `MariaDB-compat` so it needs them however I have uninstalled it. At last in returns a `Transaction check error` with this message that

> file /etc/my.cnf from install of
>   MariaDB-common-10.2.23-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from
>   package mysql-community-server-8.0.15-1.el7.x86_64

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

In [this](https://code.trev.id.au/centos-7-remove-mariadb-replace-mysql/) website I got that it needs a file named `libmysqlclient.so.18` which must be in `/usr/lib64/` directory but it is missed. How can I get this file without running command `yum install MariaDB*`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue `file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-community-server-8.0.16-2.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.3.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64` issued by removing mariadb packages.

```
yum remove MariaDB-common*
```

For more information, please refer to [Stack Exchange QA](https://serverfault.com/questions/893231/cant-install-mysql-with-error-transition-check-error/893238#893238?s=5e360482319e4609911e96fcb73ccf3a)